# Z Transform Basics

Tags: control-theory, z-transform

If you look at a z-transform table it might express z-transforms in terms of $z^{-1}$. Some also in terms of $z$. They are always expressed as negative. i.e.) $-z^{-1}$

Here is my question, how does the signal change if it is $z^{-1}$, i.e.) positive?
Is it correct to assume that the sign of the corresponding signal would change?

For example, the signal: $a^{n}u(n)$ has the z-transform, $$\frac{1}{1-az^{-1}}$$

Would, $-a^{n}u(n)$ have the z-transform, $\frac{1}{1+az^{-1}}$???

Thanks for insight

Comment: The $\mathcal{Z}$-transform is a linear operator, therefore $\mathcal{Z}[-b_n](z) =  -\mathcal{Z}[b_n](z)$

Comment: $\frac{1}{1+a z^{-1}}$ is the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of $(-a)^n 1_{n \ge 0}$

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether or not you express the Z transform using positives or negatives powers. However negative powers corresponds to delays in a data flow signal graph (in engineering). For pure control theory probably probably there other aspects you could be possibly interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $z \neq 0 $ (necessary anyway since the function has a pole at zero), the transform is equivalent to $\frac{z}{z-a}$ which is a standard case with inverse $au(n)$. $z$ is just a complex algebraic variable and can be manipulated as such.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I agree. But what about the other variant which yields $z + a$ in the denominator? Is the corresponding signal $-au(n)$?

Comment: Yes. That is correct